# Allow to access to the file system in MacOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, file, permissions, filesystems

MacOS app with Swift code:

```
let k = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "some_global_path")
```

Error:

> 2020-01-27 16:36:26.692119+0300 make_csv2[6483:225985] Metal API
>   Validation Enabled Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised
>   an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Sources”
>   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder ), NSURL=file:///Users/gerchicov/Documents/Sources, NSFilePath=/Users/gerchicov/Documents/Sources,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c110b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}: file
>   /Users/gerchicov/Documents/xcode-projects/make_csv2/make_csv2/Make.swift,
>   line 24 2020-01-27 16:36:26.757587+0300 make_csv2[6483:225985] Fatal
>   error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Sources” couldn’t be
>   opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder ), NSURL=file:///Users/gerchicov/Documents/Sources, NSFilePath=/Users/gerchicov/Documents/Sources,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c110b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}: file
>   /Users/gerchicov/Documents/xcode-projects/make_csv2/make_csv2/Make.swift,
>   line 24

Tried to change access rights via different ways - nothing works.

Comment: Make sure your app it is not sandboxed

Comment: Thanks. Checked project settings and info.plist but the problem really was with sandbox